# Проверить развернут ли iframe на весь экран

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

Хотел узнать если ли какой то способ проверить развернут ли iframe на весь экран - в моем случае это iframe видео с ютюба. Хотелось бы найти способ опознать была ли нажата кнопка развернуть на весь экран или всё таки нет.

мне это нужно для того что бы как то сделать не кликабельными кнопки канала, поделиться и смотреть позже что расположены вверху видео, с недавних пор ютюб отключил возможность их отключать при встраивании (написано что есть только для AS3 плееров но на самом деле нет). Пробую как нибудь исхитриться по другому накладывая например прозрачный див сверху на видео, но вот отследить тот момент когда видео разворачивается на весь экран не могу.
пробовал по клику через класс кнопки разворачивания поймать действие так:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".ytp-fullscreen-button", function () {
alert('d');
});
```

но так как в ифрейме естественно открывается сторонний сайт так расшарить его содержимое DOM нельзя видимо, есть ли другие способы?

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример iframe с видео с youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

немного рассуждений

1)

> Хотелось бы найти способ опознать была ли нажата кнопка развернуть на весь экран или всё таки нет.

предполагаю, что кнопка разворачивает не фрейм, а видео тэг.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode

2)  если верить тем же докам

> ```
>   function toggleFullScreen() {
>       if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
>           // разворачиваем
>       } else {
>           // сворачиваем
>       }
>   }
> ```

3)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement

> The `Document.fullscreenElement` read-only property returns the `Element` that is currently being presented in full-screen mode in this document, or `null` if full-screen mode is not currently in use.